# ServerSocket.close(). When does it throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, serversocket, ioexception

I've been wondering about this for a long time, and I've obediently been catching any possible exceptions that calling ServerSocket.close() could throw. However, not once have I seen it throwing an exception.

The [Javadocs](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#close()) state:

```
Throws:
    IOException - if an I/O error occurs when closing the socket.
```

However, as I said, I have never seen it throwing an exception. In what circumstances does an I/O error occur while closing the serversocket? You can assume the code at hand looks like this:

```
public void terminate() {
    try {
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage()); // when and how?
    }
}
```

I have searched the Internet for an answer, but couldn't come up with anything that would clarify this.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja it really depends on the implementation. There are numerous socket implementations and they could each have independent errors. Also, IOException is fairly broad and seems more like a way for the implementation to throw whatever I/O based error it wants and have it handled properly.

Comment: @Obicere I understand this. What I'm asking is, when does ServerSocket.close() throw an IOException? I don't care about the numerous other implementations.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja exactly when specified. Quite literally: `IOException - if an I/O error occurs when closing this socket.` It really does depend on the implementation of the `SocketImpl`

Comment: @Obicere Can you elaborate? I mean can you provide an example where ServerSocket.close() would throw an exception? `IOException - if an I/O error occurs when closing this socket` doesn't really mean anything if an I/O error never actually occurs, which means I'm forced into catching a non-existant exception, which in turn I think is not cool.

Comment: I think one possibility is that the connection is lost when closing the socket, or the packet to close the connection is lost. I'm not entirely sure though, since any testing would require good timing. (On remotely related topic, BufferedReader used to have a bug where it does not throw Exception when closing fail - it was tested by unplugging a removable device when the program is closing the stream. In your case, it would be safer to perform similar test, since you won't brick your network card by unplugging the connection)

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja its not a RuntimeException. If for any reason it may be thrown, it needs to be handled correctly. Sure, maybe the default implementation doesn't throw one. But say I make my own implementation and want to throw an IOException if the user's name has an `e` in it. This type of behavior needs to be specifically covered even how redundant it seems. There is a use and therefore it was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `IOException` would be thrown if the socket is already closed when you attempt to close it.

Comment: Cannot confirm this behaviour: calling two times socket.close() does _not_ throw (java8).